# Can I modify the current URL to get it into the next pages referrer?

Tags: javascript

I have a client side script on a page, which gets opend in an iframe.

The iframe gets some URL parameters, that get used by the script.

Now, when I navigate in the iframe, the old URL parameters are still accessible over `document.referrer` but lost after the next navigation.

Is it possible to take out the information from the referrer and add it into the current URL so it will reappear in the next referrer client side only?

Answer (score 1):

It won't be possible. Alternate is to have the page within the iframe setup to use the referrer page and set it up when navigating away from it.

Comment: any alternative, besides cookies, to take the added information to every following page? :\

Comment: Not really, you may have to do some server side juggling to maintain the state on multiple unrelated pages, very messy in my opinion.

Comment: how about `window.name`?